# Rails 5 + Capybara: XHR request report status 0

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, poltergeist, capybara-webkit

In the process of upgrading our application to Rails 5, I'm seeing some really baffling behavior with Javascript XHR requests during our Capybara-based feature specs.

Here is the code (CoffeeScript) in question:

```
$.ajax(
  url: "/foobar"
).done((_data, _status, _jqXhr) ->
  # *snip* all is well
  return
).fail((jqXhr) ->
  # This should be 422 but is 0 instead
  status = jqXhr.status
  console.log("AJAX request returned with error code #{status}")
  return
)
```

- Everything works when using a Rails server in `development` mode and a real browser (i.e. Chromium or Firefox)
- Poltergeist/PhantomJS reports status 0
- `capybara-webkit` also reports status 0
- Selenium Webdriver (geckodriver) correctly reports status 422

The versions of Poltergeist (1.11.0) and PhantomJS (2.1.1) stayed the same. During gem updates to Rails 5, Capybara was upgraded from 2.10.2 to 2.12.0, but I also upgraded the old branch to Capybara 2.12.0 without anything breaking, so it's likely that this isn't the problem either.

I was able to bring up the fabulous PhantomJS developer console and, in the "network" panel, saw that the status code was, also in `test` mode, 422 as expected, which means that the problem must really be somewhere in JavaScript-land.

Note that this is not a cross-origin request and the request is not aborted (the usual causes for status code 0). And since it works when in `development` mode, I'm a bit baffled who might be the culprit for this behavior.

I also tried looking at other properties and arguments to the callback function and whether I could find the status code in some other property, but haven't had any luck with that.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Qt which both capybara-webkit and phantomjs depend on older versions of.   Have you tried with the phantomjs 2.5.0 beta and latest Poltergeist?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but it's a good idea. What baffles me is why it would work with Rails 4.1 but not with Rails 5.

Comment: @ma_li after upgrading to Rails 4.2 I'm getting this situation. Did you find the cause/workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. For now I have marked those specs as "pending" until I find some time to maybe compile a custom version of PhantomJS/Poltergeist or otherwise look more closely into the problem.